# How to work with promises that rely on other promises being fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have an AngularJS promise (`users`) that relies on another promise (`userTypes`) being fulfilled before I can manipulate it. The results from both promises are being used in the controller and as such, I believe that means I need to assign the actual data from the promise to a `$scope` variable:

```
// this is all in my controller somewhere
userService.getUserTypes().then(function( data ) {

    $scope.userTypes = data;

}).then(function( data ) {

    userService.getUsers().then(function( data ) {

        $scope.users = data;

        for( var user in $scope.users ) {

            $scope.users[ user ].userType = $filter("filter")( $scope.userTypes, { id: $scope.users[ user ].userTypeID })[0];

        }

    });

});
```

Example results from `userService`:

```
// userService.getUserTypes()
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "Administrator"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "User"
    }
]

// userService.getUsers()
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sean Walsh",
        "userTypeID": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Joe Blow",
        "userTypeID": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Joe Administrator",
        "userTypeID": 1
    }
]
```

That's a contrived example (quite possibly with syntax errors), but I believe it accurately displays what I'm trying to accomplish: I want to make sure that my Angular model accurately represents the object graph from the server, so I am assigning the actual `userType` objects to the `user` rather than just representing the type with an ID.

My concern with this approach is that I can already see a little bit of "callback hell" starting with the nested `then()` calls. Is there a better way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extrapolating from other promise architectures, you can most likely return a promise from `then`, which then becomes the object the next `.then` is applied to.

```
// this is all in my controller somewhere
userService.getUserTypes().then(function( data ) {

    $scope.userTypes = data;

}).then(function(data) {

    return userService.getUsers();

}).then(function( data ) {

    $scope.users = data;

    for( var user in $scope.users ) {

        $scope.users[ user ].userType = $filter("filter")( $scope.userTypes, { id: $scope.users[ user ].userTypeID })[0];

    }

});;
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that - works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @SeanWalsh: Also, since your first `then` handler has no return statement, you should be able to combine it with the second